# cannot find dist in node_module

Tags: vue.js, node-modules

I just create Vue project dist by 'npm run build', and put that into the other project's package.json.

i try to use that, but error occured...

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'messagecomponent' in 'C:\git\vue\tester\vue-project\src'

plz help why this happen...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwzxx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqvAz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- trying to import an object from a module noy installed in your
  project directory.
- importing something from an outdated package.
- pointing to a file that does not exist.

As far as i can see the dist directory is not in your directory, so install the package which create the missing dist directory.

Either use:

```
npm install messagecomponent
```

or

```
yarn add  messagecomponent
```

If you still get the error then:

1. Delete modules:

   rm -rf node_modules
2. Delete package lock:

   rm -f package-lock.json
3. Clean up NPM cache:

   npm cache clean --force
4. Reinstall all packages:

   npm install